# What should I do with fastlane match after certificate revoked?

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match

A user has revoked the distribution certificate. After downloading the new certificate (a p12 with the key) I still cannot get

```
match appstore
```

to work.

I receive the error:

> Certificate 'XXXXXXXXXX' (stored in your git repo) is not available on
>   the Developer Portal for the user XXX@XXX.XXX Make sure to use the
>   same user and team every time you run 'match' for this Git repository.
>   This might be caused by revoking the certificate on the Dev Portal.

It is the same user and team, and I thought the manually downloading the certificate and key would fix this.

Any ideas SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best and easiest way to solve this is to use the `match nuke distribution` feature and run `match` again. This will make sure to start on a clean plate

Comment: I know, but I'm  not comfortable enough with Fastlane to support the third-party that revoked the certs in the first place. I probably will end up biting the bullet.

Comment: PS It's an incredible contribution you've made to the community @KrauseFx. Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

Good news: you don't need to use `match nuke` (which would render any existing Testflight builds undownloadable.)

Instead, you can just manually remove all certificates and provisioning profiles from the match repository (just delete the files, commit and push to `origin`.)

Next time your run `match`, it will recreate a new set of certificates and profiles (note: you may have to revoke an existing distribution certificate, if you've reached the maximum allowed number, but that beats revoking EVERYTHING, which is what `match nuke` does.)

Comment: mark this answer is accepted

Answer (score 10):

1. Go to the cert repos and delete the cert files under /certs/development and /certs/distribution.
2. Commit and push
3. Run match and it will create a new cert

Comment: could you please tell me where is the cert repo, because i'm not able to see in my repo.

Comment: This is the repo when you setup with fastlane match, not the project repo. When you use match you should see the git URL to the cert repo too.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you what's wrong. The certificates you have stored in the certificates repository is the one is revoked. Upload the new one you have in it

Comment: Can you point me at a instructions for doing this? I'm guessing doing it manually is not the preferred way.

Comment: You need to know which is the repository. Then clone it on your disk, replace the old certificate (you can simply copy and paste the new one), then commit and push the new version on your remote repository. Then it should work. If you are not the owner of that repository, you should ask him to do it

Comment: Does match take care of the p12? (I see that there is a .cer and a .p12 with the same name.)